# How to keep a list entry based on first appearance of a year?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of lists:

[image]

I've been experimenting with different loops and for statements, but can't seem to get it to work. What I'd like to do is keep the entry based on first appearence of the year. For example, `list[0]` has a year of 1966 (where `list[0][1]` is 1966). This would mean that would stay, but `list[4]` would be removed, because `list[4][1]` is also in 1966. Any ideas?

An example of something I've tried:

```
check = -1
yearlist = []
for i in list:
    check = check+1
    if list[check][1] in yearlist:
        list.remove(list[check])
    yearlist.append(list[check][1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not really need the check variable. Also, I'd use a separate list to collect the outputs while looping through the list you use as an input:

```
yearlist = []
output_list = []

for item in input_list:
    if item[1] not in yearlist:
        yearlist.append(item[1])
        output_list.append(item)

input_list = output_list
```

Next time it would be helpful to provide the data you are using too (not just as a screenshot) so one can actually reproduce it easily.

I have used this as dummy data:

```
input_list = [
        ["foo1", "1966", "bar1", "ham1"],
        ["foo1", "1956", "bar1", "ham1"],
        ["foo2", "1966", "bar2", "ham2"],
        ["foo2", "1956", "bar2", "ham2"],
        ["foo1", "1986", "bar1", "ham1"],
        ["foo2", "1986", "bar2", "ham2"],
        ["foo1", "1996", "bar1", "ham1"]
        ]
```

And it produces the following output:

```
[['foo1', '1966', 'bar1', 'ham1'], ['foo1', '1956', 'bar1', 'ham1'], ['foo1', '1986', 'bar1', 'ham1'], ['foo1', '1996', 'bar1', 'ham1']]
```

Moreover, I suggest to post purely coding related questions that do not concern data science or machine learning to https://stackoverflow.com/